# Нужны ли знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*Мать (,) Наталья Красноярская (,) работала оперной певицей*.

Comment: Без запятых в случае, если мать - церковное звание (ср. Мать Тереза Калькуттская).

Answer (score 1):

Обособление зависит от контекста, но  это скорее **уточнение**:

Мать, Наталья Красноярская, работала оперной певицей.

Answer (score 1):

[Обособление приложений](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.html)

**Приложение – имя собственное** (имя лица или кличка животного) при определяемом слове – имени нарицательном **обособляется, если** такое приложение стоит после определяемого слова и имеет пояснительное значение (перед ним можно поставить слова а именно, то есть, **а зовут его)**:

***В разговор изредка вставляет слово Любина тётка, Ксения Фроловна Горина (Песков). – В разговор изредка вставляет слово Любина тётка, а зовут её Ксения Фроловна Горина.***

**Примечание.** Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении.

Ср.: ***Один мой друг, Серёжа, решил поступать в университет (поясняется, какой именно из друзей решил поступать в университет). – Мой друг Серёжа решил поступать в университет*** (такого пояснения в данном контексте нет, причем именно имя собственное является в данном случае определяемым словом, а нарицательное – приложением).

**В Вашем случае приложение обособляется, можно вставить "а зовут её".**